# How does so much time pass between Prison Break seasons 1 and 2?

Tags: continuity, prison-break

In Prison Break, season 1 ends with the escapees running in a field at night with the cops right behind them. Season 2 starts with the escapees running through a lush forest during the daytime with the cops right behind them.

1. Were the escapees and cops running all night? Why wasn't day break shown?
2. How did the scene change from a field to a forest all of the sudden?

Answer (score 3):

Lets take the questions one at a time.

> Were the escapees and cops running all night? Why wasn't day break shown?

Its not uncommon for fugitives to keep running till they feel they have put some distance between themselves and their pursuers. And I bet the cops were willing to pursue them all night. After all there were some high value targets in the bunch like *Burrows* (the convicted killer of the VP's brother) and *John Abruzzi* (a mob boss). But do you think an episode dedicated to the first night of the chase would had added any value?

> How did the scene change from a field to a forest all of the sudden?

Terrains change! Its not inconceivable to start from a point in the plains and ending up in the thick after a few hours of hike.

Comment: A whole episode isn't required but at least a single flash scene to provide some continuity would have helped a lot-- especially one of them entering a forest or night falling as they ran.

Answer (score 1):

I think they showed it like that to make the viewers understand that the cops were behind them from the moment they escaped.